# VS2010 extension, using MEF tagger, want to use code model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, margin, vsx, envdte

I want to write a visual studio 2010 extension displaying a margin glyph on each class, method, property, field and event definition (tooltip/popup window on click with additional info).

The new MEF based framework is really neat but the only thing I can tag in order to create margin glyphs are snapshotspans. unfortunately they dont have any sort of code model or structuring and i am forced to search for class names, etc. by string parsing => absolutely not what i want to do.

We found out that we can use

```
[Import]
internal SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider;
```

to retreive a DTE object for the current document. Unfortunately we still have problems to call `fileCodeModel.CodeElementFromPoint()` because we have no TextPoint object.

Does somebody know how to convert a SnapshotSpan to a TextPoint?

Is there any other way to directly tag the code model instead of the text? Only thing I found on google has been: [Visual Studio Extensibility / Margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985697/visual-studio-extensibility-margins) - also forgeting about how to convert from SnapshotSpan to TextPoint : (

Best regards.
D.R.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this myself, but you might be able to figure it out by looking at the code to [RapidMEF](http://rapidmef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I can't see how to get RapidMEF's source code, doesn't seem to be open source.

Comment: RapidMEF (accordingly to our Reflector research) uses a c# language parser from an undocumented, unofficial MS library (classes in microsoft restricted namespace, etc.)

This isn't too useful to us, thanks anyways.

Comment: @D.R. I don't think there is currently a public API that lets you access the code model.  It should be coming in "Roslyn": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/16/hiring-for-roslyn.aspx

Comment: May I ask for your personal opinion: Would you write your own language parsers or give this undocumented libraries a go?

Comment: @D.R. There's no guarantee the undocumented libraries will be the same or work the same across different versions of Visual Studio.  If you depend on them your extension would likely break for each new version.  So I wouldn't recommend using them in general.  I also would recommend avoiding writing your own parser if you can.  I believe the Mono project has a C# compiler written entirely in C#.  So you might be able to take its parser and use it.

Comment: @D.R. If you want clean integration with the compiler hosted in-process in Visual Studio 2010, you'll need to reference the internal library. Other options result in slow operation, and when it comes to productivity the choice was obvious: I work with Visual Studio very often, and upgrade to the next major version of Visual Studio very rarely. I'm using the internal library for this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a55d546-0cb2-4991-a002-e6be8ce09f08